# FHIR Element Definition max/min

Tags: hl7-fhir

What does max/min mean on the root element of a resource or extension?

```
<element>
  <path value="Patient" />
  <min value="0" />
  <max value="*" />
  ...snip...
</element>
```

The cardinality allowed in a containing structure like Bundle?  Doesn't make sense to me....

Answer (score 1):

For a resource, it doesn't mean anything.  For an extension, it places constraints on what the cardinality is allowed to be for a slice instantiating that constraint in a profile.  For example, if an extension has a cardinality of 1..5, then if that extension is referenced inside a profile, the minimum cardinality of that constraint element must be at least 1 and the maximum no more than 5.  Most of the time this will just be used to indicate whether the extension will be allowed to repeat or not.

Comment: What happens if I use the same extension in two different named slices? Is the cardinality constrained per slice? Or for the whole resource?

Comment: The cardinality is constrained in terms of its appearance within a particular node.  An extension is already a slice (on extension).  If you sub-slice an extension, that doesn't impact the total number of times the extension can appear.